# How to print the output of Process Builder Line wise

Tags: java, jsp

I have code to Print output of ipconfig command using process builder. But I want to print one Line at a time. The idea is to remove few line from the output which the client doesn't want to see in output. Following is the code.

```
{
File file=new File("D:\\LC");
String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
probuilder.directory(file);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String readline;
while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    out.println(readline);
    out.println("<br>");
}
}
```

Here in While loop readline stores the entire value in single shot and hence I can not remove some info from out put. I want readline to take values one line at a time so that by using loops and conditions i can remove line I don't want to print.
Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, it should be `probuilder.start()` not `pb.start()`.

I have run the program it works as expected, `readLine()` reads line by line.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] cmd = { "CMD", "/C", "dir" };
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process p = probuilder.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String readline;
    int i = 0;
    while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(++i + " " + readline);
    }
}
```

Output:-

`1  Volume in drive C is System
2  Volume Serial Number is 1C25-498E
3 
4  Directory of C:\juno\ksaravan\workspace\CommandPrompt
5 
6 01/13/2015  12:47 PM    <DIR>          .
7 01/13/2015  12:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
8 02/13/2015  10:57 AM               623 .classpath
9 01/05/2015  12:48 PM               389 .project`

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Sorry it was a typing error it should probuilder.start(). It worked. Thanks a Lot.